# Combinatorics: Find the subset

Tags: combinatorics

I am on the combinatorics unit in my book, and there is a question that I don't even know how to start solving. Can anyone point me in the right direction? It is:

> Becky likes to watch DVDs each evening. How many DVDs must she have, if she is able to watch every evening for $24$ consecutive evenings during her winter break?
>
> a) A different subset of DVDs?
>   b) A different subset of three DVDs?

I am not sure what the question means by subset of DVDs and is Becky watching a new DVD every evening or the same DVD? I'm pretty lost.

The answer in the book is a) at least 5 and b) at least 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $S$ is the set of her DVDs and $D$ is its subset, $D \subset S$.

In question a) there is no limit for number of elements of $D$.
In question b) the set $D$ must have exactly 3 elements.

In both cases the subsets $D_1, D_2, \dots, D_{24}$ must be different.

For example, if she had $5$ DVSs, then $S = \{1, 2, 3, 4, 5\}$, and $D_i$ may be:

\begin{aligned}
D_1 &= \{1\} \\
D_2 &= \{1, 2\} \\
D_3 &= \{1, 2, 3, 4, 5\} \\
D_4 &= \{1, 2, 4, 5\} \\
D_5 &= \{1, 2, 3\} \\
D_6 &= \{1, 2, 3, 4\} \\
\end{aligned}

and so on, as no one of subsets is repeated.

So that:

- question a) is about the power set of $S$ (the set of all its subsets),
- question b) is about 3-element's combinations.

Let $n$ be the number of (unknown) elements of set $S$. Then:

- a) Power set of $S$ has $2^n$ elements (including the empty set).
- b) The number of 3-element's combinations will be $_nC_3 = \frac {n(n-1(n-2)}6$.

In both cases it need be greater of equal 24, so

- for a) the result is $\color{red}5$ (because $2^5 = 32$, while $2^4 = \ only\ 16$),
- for b) the result is $\color{red}7$ (because $_7C_3 = 35$, while $_6C_3 =  \ only\  20$).

Comment: It's not clear to me if $D$ is supposed to be nonempty in part a).  This is a criticism of the original question, not of your answer.

Comment: @saulspatz, you are right, it is not 100% clear from the question. But from the sentence "Becky likes to watch DVDs **each** evening" I suppose that the empty subset is not allowed.

Comment: But what does the 24 consecutive nights mean in terms of the answer and how is the answer for part a atleast 5?

Comment: @Sam It means that there have to be at least $24$ different subsets.

Comment: @saulspatz, the word *"consecutive"* has no meaning for solutions. Number 5 has nothing with part a), I chose it only for example. I extended my answer.